# How to do "field pointers" in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I have a number of Solr documents with dynamic fields which duplicate data that is in fields in other documents. The trouble is, the data in these dynamic fields gets stale whenever the referenced content changes.

Is there some way to have a "field pointer" so that these cross-references always stay in sync?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the data in the same document and use the [CopyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields) setting

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the scenario correctly, you are maintaining duplicate data with your documents which basically points to other referenced data.
There are no field pointers in Solr.

You can probably use [Solr Join](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join), which will help you reference the data rather than maintaining it with each document. So that you just need to update it once and it would be referenced correctly by the other documents.

Solr Join is a Solr 4.0 feature, and probably needs to be patched up with the build used.

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but unfortunately Solr 4.0 is pre-release right now and we likely can't use it. :( I may mark this as accepted if no others come up.

Comment: You can try to apply the patch to your current build, and see how it works for you. Need not upgrade to Solr 4.0